# What is the overhead of dependency injection in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-changedetection

We have a quite large Angular 2/4 application that uses reactive forms, with hundreds of form controls.

Is there a significant overhead just by injecting a ChangeDetectorRef instance in about 200 form control components?

Change detection reference usage:

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: and what do you intend to do with them?

Comment: I call detectChanges() manually, after component init because i want to restyle some of them, and my ChangeDetectionStrategy is set to OnPush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight overhead resulting from the need to create a `ViewRef_` wrapper around the component View object. The `ChangeDetectorRef` itself is just an instance of `ViewRef_`.

Here is the relevant snippet fro the sources where`resolveDep` is the function called when Angular processes dependencies for a constructor:

```
function resolveDep(view, elDef, allowPrivateServices, depDef, notFoundValue) {
    ...
    while (view) {
        if (elDef) {
            switch (tokenKey$$1) {
                ...
                case ChangeDetectorRefTokenKey: {
                    var cdView = findCompView(view, elDef, allowPrivateServices);
                    return createChangeDetectorRef(cdView); <------ create a wrapper
                }

export function createChangeDetectorRef(view: ViewData): ChangeDetectorRef {
  return new ViewRef_(view);
}
```

Read these articles to learn more about the underlying View object:

- [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02#cbe4)
- [Here is why you will not find components inside Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c#4e19)